# How to launch Boxee's web browser?

Tags: browser, boxee

I am building a Boxee app and would like to, in response to certain user actions, open Boxee's web browser with a given URL. Boxee's documentation is a little light here (by my eyes).

Is this possible to do and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the API here http://developer.boxee.tv/JavaScript_API#browser

I guess navigate is the thing you re looking for: navigate(url:String):Void

browser.navigate("http://www.yourpage.com");